# How to integrate junit/pmd/findbugs report into hudson build email?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, report, email

my team is looking into using hudson as our continuous integration software, 1 problem that we  try to figure out is to integrate the reports of junit/pmd/findbugs etc into the build email that get sent to the team.

the graph/reports on the dashboard are nice and all, but people usually want to just read the email and not clicking the links. i tried to use the ext-email plugin, but that doesn't provide much help related to this. is there any way i can get those info into the build email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you note, the email-ext plugin doesn't have too much documentation, and you'll probably have to jump through some hoops, but it should be possible.

Check out [this blog post](http://joesondow.blogspot.com/2009/10/fancy-hudson-email.html) as a useful tutorial, which demonstrates much improved email output, as you can see:

[image: Jenkins example email output]

Answer (score 0):

My answer won't help you that much, but can bring some hope ;)
For code metrics we use [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/), it integrates CheckStyle, PMD, FireBugs and some other plugins (like Cobertura etc.), to see it in action click [here](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/). It can be integrated with Hudson, and there is plugin to send emails but they are as you said, just links to dashboard. There is also [jira report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-1301) opened, feel free to vote, as well as describe what you need (if you decide to use Sonar).

PS. there are a lot of addition plugins for sonar, just [have a look](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Plugin+Library)